# Expand Label vertically based on quantity of text using Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uilabel

I have a `UIlabel` linked to a property that can contain text of many different possible lengths.

How can I get the label to expand vertically to accommodate different quantities of text?

I have set lines to 0 in storyboard.  And I've experimented with different heights in the Size Inspector.  If I make the height large enough, the second line will display.  But then if there is only one line, it leaves a lot of blank space.  If the label is only about the size of one line, I am only seeing one line of text that ends at edge of label.

I have also tried the following code but it is not having the desired effect.

```
self.myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [self.myLabel sizeToFit];
```

Would prefer not to use auto layout if possible unless there is no other way.

Comment: Are you using Autolayout or Auto resizing masks?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30448659/341994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the following piece of code. I'm not sure about your UI configuration but the code usually works:

```
self.myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
self.myLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
self.myLabel.text = @"your long text";
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(200.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX); // you might change 200.0 to whatever suits for you

CGSize requiredSize = [self.myLabel sizeThatFits:maxSize];
//with Auto Layout you need to use: CGSize requiredSize = [self.myLabel systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];

self.myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.myLabel.frame.origin.x, self.myLabel.frame.origin.y, requiredSize.width, requiredSize.height); //use whatever left/top you find suitable
```

### Edit

If you want the below code to work expectedly, **you must stick to Autoresizing not Auto Layout** as you might have preferred.

Picture 1 below, shows the checkbox you must uncheck to enable Autoresizing instead of Auto Layout.

Then you need to reconsider the autoresizing masks applied to the label. You might set the autoresizing masks `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin` and `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin` and **absolutely nothing else**. Please see the Picture 2 below:

[image: Auto layout]

[image: Autoresizing masks]

Once you have set the autoresizing masks, create a method like following in your viewcontroller class:

```
-(void)adjustLabelWithText:(NSString*)text {
    self.myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    self.myLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    self.myLabel.text = text;
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 2 * self.myLabel.frame.origin.x, CGFLOAT_MAX); //I have used current window width - some margin to the both sides. you could change it to watever suitable for you
    CGSize requiredSize = [self.myLabel sizeThatFits:maxSize];
    self.myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.myLabel.frame.origin.x, self.myLabel.frame.origin.y, requiredSize.width, requiredSize.height);
}
```

And call the method from `viewWillLayoutSubviews`:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    [self adjustLabelWithText:@"Chapter One\n "
     "A Stop on the Salt Route\n "
     "1000 B.C.\n "
     "As they rounded a bend in the path that ran beside the river, Lara recognized the silhouette of a fig tree atop a nearby hill. The weather was hot and the days were long. The fig tree was in full leaf, but not yet bearing fruit."]; //whatever long text you prefer
}
```

This will ensure that you receive the desired effect, irrespective of the orientation change that you are possibly struggling with.

Comment: should label in fifth line be self.mylabel?    Also in last line, am getting error 'no member named left in struct cgpoint'

Comment: do I need to set size.width and size.height?  Getting 'use of undeclared identifier 'size'

Comment: I marked this right as it appeared to be right, however, I am now finding that it still depends on the height of the label in storyboard.  If the height in storyboard is too small, only one line shows.  If the height is big enough, all lies show but then it takes up too much space if the text is short.  Is there a way to remove dependency on height of label in storyboard?

Comment: @user1904273 I guess you are struggling with autoresizing masks applied to the label. Please see my updated answer above.

Comment: I am using Xcode 6.  Currently there are no constraints.  Is what you are suggesting the same as  adding 2 new constraints for the top and left margin?

Comment: @user1904273 doesn't depend on the version of xcode and I'm not asking you to add any constraint but to set Autoresizing masks as depicted in the picture. Click on the label, select Size Inspector in the right pane of Xcode and please verify that your Autoresizing masks conform with the picture. These masks has nothing to do with Auto Layout constraints. If you don't see the Autoresizing portion in your Size inspector that means you have Auto Layout turned on in File Inspector. If so go File Inspector and check it off and everything should work as expected!

Comment: auto layout is turned on in File Inspector.  When I went to turn it off, it gave me warnings about the page not displaying correctly on other iPhone devices.  Do you think it's safe to turn off?

Comment: @user1904273 At least as per your requirements, as you prefer to use Autoresizing masks over AutoLayout. If you wanna go with Auto Layout the story would be totally different.